# How to get $L(1)$ from $L(a_0+a_1x)=(a_0−a_1)+(a_0+a_1)x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I just started learning about linear transformations and part of an example in our material confuses me:

Let $L: \mathcal{P_1}\rightarrow \mathcal{P_2}$ for which 
$$L(a_0+a_1x)=(a_0-a_1)+(a_0+a_1)x^2.$$

Given that $S=(1,x)$ is a base of the polynomial space $\mathcal{P_1}$ and $\mathcal{T}=(1,x,x^2)$ is a base of the polynomial space $\mathcal{P_2}$, define the matrix of the linear transformation $L$.

The images of the base vectors of $\mathcal{P}_1$ are $L(1)=1+x^2$ and $L(x)=-1+x^2$.

The example continues from here but this is actually the part that I don't understand. How did we get $L(1)=1+x^2$ and $L(x)=-1+x^2$ ? I understand if, for example, we have a linear transformation $L: \mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ for which $L(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1-3x_2+2x_3, x_1+x_2-2x_3)$ and we want $L(1,0,0)$ since it is (1-0+0, 1+0-0)=(1,1) but how do you get the image of a set that has only one element?

Sorry if my text is a little bit confusing, english is not my first language and I don't know if I have just understood something wrong and I don't know if my explanation was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to compute $L(1)$, but are given instead $L(a_{0}+a_{1}x)$ for any $a_{0},a_{1} \in \mathbb{R}$. How can you make the argument of $L$ be $1$? Well, choosing $a_{0}=1$ and $a_{1} = 0$ works, and in that case we obtain 
$$(1-0)+(1+0)x^{2} = 1+x^{2}$$
Similarly, choosing $a_{0}=0$ and $a_{1}=1$, we obtain
$$L(x)=L(0+1\cdot x) = (0-1)+(0+1)x^{2} = -1+x^{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $1=a_0+a_1x$ with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=0$. This gives

$L(1)=(a_0-a_1)+(a_0+a_1)x^2=(1-0)+(1+0)x^2=1+x^2$.

A similar computation gives $L(x)=-1+x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to express the polynomials you insert in $L$ in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$:

$$1\equiv a_0+a_1x\Rightarrow a_0=1,\ a_1=0$$
And
$$x\equiv a_0+a_1x\Rightarrow a_0=0,\ a_1=1$$

From here,  you just need plug these values in.

This is actually exactly expressing your inputs in terma of the basis $\{1,x\}$